# How atopsar calculates HDD load?

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, io

I have dedicated to MySQL InnoDB log files (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile0) HDD - `sda`. And atopsar shows big load to this HDD

`atopsar -d 60`:

```
13:02:10  disk           busy read/s KB/read  writ/s KB/writ avque avserv _dsk
13:03:10  sda             59%    4.4     4.0    45.3     6.2   1.0  11.88 ms
13:04:10  sda             60%    4.5     4.0    45.6     6.1   1.0  11.98 ms
13:05:10  sda             58%    4.2     4.0    44.7     6.0   1.0  11.94 ms
```

`dstat -tdD total,sda 60`:

```
----system---- -dsk/total----dsk/sda--
     time     | read  writ: read  writ
24-09 13:11:24|  23k  912k:9689B  391k
24-09 13:12:24|  33k  971k:  16k  270k
24-09 13:13:24|  16k  893k:  14k  235k
24-09 13:14:24|  18k  963k:  16k  254k
```

`pt-ioprofile -cell sizes`:

```
     total      pread       read     pwrite      write      fsync       open      close      lseek      fcntl filename
    905728          0          0     905728          0          0          0          0          0          0 /var/mysqllog/mysql/ib_logfile0
```

200-400Kb per second does not seems to be much to show busy > 50%. Specially considering that the only files on HDD are MySQL InnoDB log files and (from the [InnoDB blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/redo_logging_in_innodb)).:

> The redo log files are used in a circular fashion. This means that the redo logs are written from the beginning to end of first redo log file, then it is continued to be written into the next log file, and so on till it reaches the last redo log file. Once the last redo log file has been written, then redo logs are again written from the first redo log file.

So the question is why the load is so big, Is it real physical capability of HDD?

Seems to be the load is calculated (all request, read+write)*avserv/1000. For the first atopsar line calculation is as follows: (4.4 + 45.3)*11.88 / 1000 = 0.59